# Applicability of Dijkstra's algorithm to hypergraphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

When I search for Dijkstra's algorithm and hypergraphs, I don't get any results discussing it. The Wikipedia page regarding Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't mention hypergraphs and the one regarding hypergraphs doesn't mention Dijkstra's algorithm. When I search for shortest path algorithms for hypergraphs, I only get results with complicated algorithms.

But when I look at Dijkstra's algorithm, I can't seem to see anything in it where it uses the fact that each edge only connects two nodes.

[Wikipedia states this pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue):

```
1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
2      dist[source] ← 0                                    // Initialization
3
4      create vertex set Q
5
6      for each vertex v in Graph:           
7          if v ≠ source
8              dist[v] ← INFINITY                          // Unknown distance from source to v
9              prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                         // Predecessor of v
10
11         Q.add_with_priority(v, dist[v])
12
13
14     while Q is not empty:                              // The main loop
15         u ← Q.extract_min()                            // Remove and return best vertex
16         for each neighbor v of u:                      // only v that is still in Q
17             alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v) 
18             if alt < dist[v]
19                 dist[v] ← alt
20                 prev[v] ← u
21                 Q.decrease_priority(v, alt)
22
23     return dist, prev
```

The only time this algorithm mentions connections is in line 16, where it says "for each neighbor v of u".

Could I simply use this algorithm for hypergraphs and only get correct results?

Comment: Hint: try to model your hypergraph as shortest-path equivalent graph.

Comment: @Raphael I know that I can simply transform my hypergraph into a regular graph where each hyperedge is a clique. So you're saying I can just do the same thing implicitly?

Comment: I haven't worked through the details myself, but usually that is possible.

Comment: I believe that finding the shortest hyper path is NP-hard for general hyper-graphs. However, for certain cases you can find efficient algorithms. Look at Liang Huang 2008, Gallo et al. 1993 and Nielsen et al. 2005. A hyperpath is fundamentally different than a "regular" path in a regular graph. So regarding your question of just replacing the hyperedges with cliques, depends on what you want. In a shortest hyperpath, you usually want entire hyperedges in the solution which is not equivalent to what you get in the clique version.

Comment: @DariusTheGreat why it is not equivalent?

Comment: @salcc I have been away from this topic for a while now, and you should look at the references I mentioned for a more detailed answer. Intuitively, if you go down an edge in a hypergraph, you end up being at multiple nodes simultaneously (imagine an h-edge A->{B,C}). If you replace this by two edges, at any point, you're either at node B or C, but never in both at the same time. So in general the algorithms don't transfer 1-to-1 between graphs and hypergraphs.

Comment: @DariusTheGreat I have a followed up question if you don't mind: Can we apply Gallo's algorithm to undirected hypergraph? I found this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.0082.pdf, and the complexity of Gallo's algorithm is stated in the right column of page 7, which is pretty impressive. But Gallo's paper (Ref. 12 therein) seems to deal with directed hypergraph, hence I am not sure if the same algorithm can be applied to undirected ones. Thanks!

Comment: Also, from Sec 5 of this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397516002097#se0050, it is stated/proved that the shortest path problem for the directed hypergraph is NP hard (Theorem 5.1, the theorem itself does not have the word "directed", but the proof below is for directed hypergraph). Hence it seems to contradict to the table in previous paper. Did I misunderstand anything here?